# What is a usecase for Java AtomicReference#getAndSet?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, atomicreference

What is a usecase for Java `AtomicReference#getAndSet`? In other words, is it correct assumption, that if the only method from `AtomicReference` that I use in my code is `AtomicReference#getAndSet`, then I do not need `AtomicReference` at all, just a `volatile` variable would be enough?

For example, if I have the next code:

```
private final AtomicReference<String> string = new AtomicReference<>("old");

public String getAndSet() {
    return string.getAndSet("new");
}
```

, isn't it always doing exactly the same as

```
private volatile String string = "old";

public String getAndSet() {
    String old = string;
    string = "new";
    return old;
}
```

from the caller's point of view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, these are not equivalent.  The difference is that `getAndSet` does *both operations* atomically, not just an atomic get and then an atomic set.

`getAndSet` is always guaranteed to return *exactly* the value that was stored in the reference *right before* the new value was set.  The volatile version might "skip" values inserted by other threads.